# Modules as Namespaces In Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module

## background

we have this file structure:

```
app/services/promo/promotion_expire.rb
app/services/payment/code_pen_subscription.rb
```

and the modules/classes defined below.

**promotion_expire.rb**

```
module Promo
  class PromotionExpire

  end
end
```

**code_pen_subscription.rb**

```
module Payment
  class CodePenSubscription

    def new_suscription_from_promo
       ##stuff
       Promo::PromotionExpire.new.expire_single(@user, true)
       ##/stuff
    end

  end
end
```

## problem

In production only, we got an exception

`NameE​rror:​ unin​itial​ized ​const​ant P​aymen​t::Pr​omo::​Promo​tionE​xpire`

To fix, we changed `Promo::PromotionExpire` to `::Promo::PromotionExpire` in `new_subscription_from_promo`, which tells ruby to look from root of module hierarchy.  But we don't know why

1. this only happens in production (autoload path?)
2. why it only happens in `CodePenSubscription`, not others, because we use this idiom elsewhere.